How to Speed Up Response Streaming from Agent in InvokeAgent API (EventStream)?
I'm working with an API that uses the InvokeAgent endpoint with EventStream to interact with an agent. The current setup works, but I'm experiencing some latency issues and would like to speed up the response transmission. Here are the details of my setup and the steps I've taken so far:
Context:

API Endpoint: InvokeAgent with EventStream (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/bedrock-agent-runtime/client/invoke_agent.html)

The knowledge base associated with the agent has 250 small flat files and 2 pdfs.

The agent has 3 groups of actions associated with it

I am using a lambda to invoke the agent, using boto3.

Current Performance: The agent's response is functional but has noticeable latency that impacts the user experience. On average it takes 10 to 12 seconds to transmit the entire response, including cases of 18 seconds. Here some performance data.


enter image description here
What I've Tried:

Consuming the data while it is being transmitted, however, the problem is the transmission, as the process of putting all the pieces together is quite fast.

Are there specific configurations or best practices for speeding up EventStream responses in the InvokeAgent API?
What are some common pitfalls that might cause delays in response streaming that I should be aware of?
Are there any tools or techniques recommended for profiling and diagnosing latency issues in this context?
I would like to have response times between 3 and 6 seconds.
